# Node orm2: orm.connect callback is not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, orm, node-orm2

I would like to try out [node orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2), with **sqlite**. I tried the example code, and changed mysql to sqlite. It looks like this:

```
var orm = require("orm");

orm.connect('sqlite://D:/orm_test/database.db', function (err, db) {

    // ...

});
```

I don't get any error, or warning. Just nothing happens. The callback is not called at all.

It does not work, even if I create `database.db` before

Comment: i suspect you d better use the object mode to define your connection string [see](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/blob/master/lib/ORM.js#L74). If i run `url.parse('sqlite://D:\\orm_test\\database.db', true);`, it s kind of ugly. What is weird is that you said the cb is not invoked. This should be reported as a bug.

Comment: Did you even install `npm sqlite`?

Comment: of course I did

Comment: Which npm you installed? I tested it and it connected simply. I can share the project if you want.

Comment: I've installed `sqlite3`. npm version is: `3.7.3` nodejs version is: `6`

Comment: Well, I did the same, but the call back fires..

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the callback is only called when the connection is done successfully (or unsuccessfully)...
So if your path is incorrect (for any reason, and your connection is NOT explicitly unsuccessfull), maybe there is no callback ?

You can avoid callback if you listen for the connect event directly as this :

```
var orm = require('orm');
var db = orm.connect('sqlite://D:/orm_test/database.db');
db.on('connect', function(err) {
  if (err) return console.error('Connection error: ' + err);
  // doSomething()...
});
```

The connection URL is like :

```
driver://username:password@hostname/database?option=value
```

You can use the debug option to prints queries into the console, maybe there will be more informations ?

EDIT :
Well, I just tried to use it and did that :

```
// REQUIRES
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var orm = require("orm");
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

// SERVER CONFIGURATION
var port = 5050;

// APP CONFIGURATION
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// ROUTES
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    orm.connect('sqlite://C:/Users/Me/Documents/Projects/test/database.db', function(err, db){
    console.log('connected to this db : ' + JSON.stringify(db));
    });
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.info('Server successfully started, listening on port ' + port);
});
```

And it works... JSON.stringify shows what is the content of DB Object in the console.
Does your code looks like this ?

Comment: Still there is nothing. `on('connect', ...` callback is never called

Comment: Does the debug option = true prints something ?